# Combinatorial Problem: Stacking Books on a Shelf

Tags: combinatorics

A shelf has five books. In how many ways can we stack some or all of these books? The stack can contain only one book.

**Attempt**: Why is my reasoning wrong? $5! \times 2^5$, with each book having two possibilities: being inside the stack or not being in it.

Comment: That's far too large.  To get the books $1,2$ stacked that way you could have taken the orders $12345, 12354, 12435, 12453, 12534, 12543$ and then chosen to suppress the back three.

Comment: Just sum over the possible choices for the number of books, it's easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing "The stack can contain only one book", I presume you mean The stack can *even* contain only one book, because without the additional word, it means that the stack can contain *only* one book which has the trivial answer of $5$

I hope you are familiar with the notation for permutations  ${}^nP_r \equiv {}^nC_r \times r!$, or in the notation favored on this forum, $\binom{n}{r}\times r!$

So using the simpler permutation notation for this problem, the answer is
$${\large{}^5P_1 + {}^5P_2 + {}^5P_3 + {}^5P_4 + {}^5P_5}$$

or if you want to condense it
$$\large\sum_{r=1}^5 {} ^5P_r$$

---

You had two errors in your attempt

- $2^5$ includes $0$ books in the stack
- You are multiplying all combinations by $5!$ instead of the actual number of books you put in the stack